# Как настроить 3G модем Pantech UM175VW под Debian Squeeze?

Tags: debian, squeeze

Модем определяется, я выбираю из списка провайдеров "Интертелеком", подключаюсь, но ничего не происходит. Что можно предпринять? (я на линуксе второй день)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помогло вот это.

wvdialconf - определился модем. В wvdial.conf прописал -

```
Modem = /dev/ttyACM0Init1 = ATZInit2 = ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0Phone = #777Username = ITPassword = IT
```

Запустил Gnome-ppp с правами администратора > sudo gnome-ppp. Далее “Система -> Администрирование -> Пользователи и группы”. Разрешаем себе использовать Dial-Up  соединением, отмечая галочкой пункт “Соединяться с Интернет через модем”.

Всё работает!

Правда, хотелось бы, чтобы всё было через GUI, а не из под рута с запущенным процессом в терминале. Может, кто-то подскажет, как это решить?